# Find whether there is a path in a matrix or not?

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Given a square matrix of size N. It consist of elements 0,1 and 2. We have to whether there exist any path from position [0,0] to [N-1,N-1]. We can move in four direction up, down, left, right.

We can move through only 0's. 1 is blocking element, **while 2 is movable block which can be shifted to make path if possible.**

I am able to solve simple maze problem through recursion, but how should I approach movable blocks.

```
Example 
Matrix :
0 1 1 0 1
0 2 0 0 1
1 0 1 0 1
1 1 2 0 0
```

Here we can make path if we move 2 from position [1,1] to [2,1]

Comment: By writing code. Not by dumping your homework assignment here.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to solve the simple maze, this should not be a hard problem. The solution should be just an extension of the simple maze.

You can use BFS or DFS to solve the problem. The trick here is to extend the original state (x,y), your current position to be (x, y, x0, y0, x1, y1, xn-1, yn-1) where (xi, yi) is the position of ith movable block.

Moreover, instead of 4 directional movements(move up, down, left, right), you should have 4 more possible shifting actions, shift the left movable block left (if exists), up block up, right block right, down block down. So 8 possible actions to transfer from one state to another.

Hope this helps.